# today is there any browser that do not support websocket?

Tags: websocket, socket.io, spring-websocket, sockjs

Isn't websocket enough without using socket.io or sockjs?

i know that some broswer do not support websockt, so we can use socket.io or sockjs.
but even if IE, 11 version and 10 version is supporting websocket. and the order version of IE that do not support for websocket is only used in very old OS like XP.
so in real life, is there any reason that we need to use socket.io or sockjs??
i think websocket is enough

Answer (score 0):

caniuse.com is a very helpful resource for such questions: https://caniuse.com/websockets

Turns out that *Opera Mini* does not have support for web sockets.